# How to see what the builders are building right now?

Tags: castle-clash

I have 5 builders, and they usually all busy building all sorts of different stuff, each taking different time.

I like to plan in advance how to manage my resources, e.g. if I have over a full day until a builder is free, I will invest the mana in Crests and gold in walls, otherwise I'll start saving them.

Is there an easy way to see the list of what my builders are busy building and how long until each of them finish, at any given moment? So far I have to just scroll around and watch for the time headers, which is quite cumbersome.

Comment: Also a pain in the backside if the time bar is obscured by a hero...

Comment: @JonK true, been there too... :/

Answer (score 2):

At the point in time, there is no easy method to track the buildings your workers are constructing on.

IGG also does not plan on implementing such a feature. If enough people suggest this, then they may decide to put it in the game. (One way to garner support is by using the forum polls.)

Comment: Thanks, any links to support the bad news?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There's no official report denying this feature, however I'm a CC mod and we get a general outline of what's to come. Feel free to drop by start a suggestion poll. If it gets enough traction, it might get released in a future update. http://cc.forum.igg.com/

Comment: [Done](http://cc.forum.igg.com/topic?fcid=370&ctid=218426) - not familiar with that forum rules/format so hope it's fine. (didn't see a way to start a poll)